# getting error The expression "[MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals(net7.0, 4.0)" cannot be evaluated even with versions 7 and 4 installed

Tags: .net, .net-core, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI cli to generate a .Net project. Here is the command I used

`openapi-generator-cli generate -i openapi.json  -o core7.0 --additional-properties=targetFramework=net7.0`

This results in a project that makes references to .net4.5 assemblies. I'm not sure why OpenApi is doing this when the assemblies being referenced are also available in Core 6.0. The windows 10 machine I am opening this project in using Visual Studio 22 gives the error

> expression "[MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals(net7.0, 4.0)" cannot
> be evaluated

Here is Core7.0 SDK installed for my Windows 64 bit machine
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.400-windows-x64-installer
Installing .Net 4.0 got me an error saying that it is already installed on this OS.

What is the cause of this error and how to fix this?